# How to assign issue to myself at Github?

Tags: git, github

I am asked to assign an issue to myself, the issue is created by someone else. I found this how to guide at [help.github.com](https://help.github.com/articles/assigning-issues-and-pull-requests-to-other-github-users/).

I can see the issue list indeed and I have the "exclamation mark with circle, open" for the issue, but I don't have the check box mentioned in step 4. The repository is not mine.

How can I assign the issue? Do I miss any right?

I just googled some words stating "Only admin can assign task to assignee", is that true?

Answer (score 16):

To be able to assign issues to yourself or to others [you have to be the owner or a collaborator of the repository](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/). If the repository is owned by an organization [you have to be part of a "Write access team", an "Admin access team", or the "Owners team" to assign issues](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/).

Your options are to either ask the owner/an admin of the repository to assign the issue to you, or to ask the owner if (s)he can add you as a collaborator. When you are a collaborator or part of one of the previously specified teams you can assign an issue in the way you [described already (help.github.com)](https://help.github.com/articles/assigning-issues-and-pull-requests-to-other-github-users/).